# VS Code - changing the focus after deleting a file in the explorer view

Tags: visual-studio-code

After I delete a file in the explorer view in VS Code, the focus jumps to the file that had the focus before the deleted one. This can often be a long way away up or down the tree and I completely lose where I was. I would much rather the focus just went to the file that has now taken the place of the deleted file in the explorer (ie the next one in the list). Is there a setting for this?

Comment: I assume you have `"explorer.autoReveal": true`? If so, do you want to keep it that way?

Comment: Thanks for the autoReveal tip. I did reply a while ago but it seems to have been lost.  Still not quite right though - I was hoping I could get the focused tree item to be the one that has just moved up into the place of the deleted one, just like file explorer in windows (or any other tree view)